# SSRS report is not generating

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

i am new to ssrs reporting.

i have a website to generate ssrs report. it was working properly till last week.

when i try to setup this website in my new system it is not working.

my old system has SQL server 2012 as database, it works in windows 8.

my new system has SQL server 2017 as database , it works in windows 10 pro.

i am using the same binary code of website, same rdlc files, and database configurations are also same.

but when i try to generate report of 15-10-2019(dd/MM/yyyy) date report is not generating, and if i give 10-10-2019(dd/MM/yyyy) as input the report is generated correctly.

the problem that i find was the date and month is interchanged. how can i solve this problem.

i already reinstalled my system,SQL server and reporting service. but it gives the same error. but this is working properly in other systems.

please help me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would check and see if your language settings have been changed. I have ran into an issue where the language was set to English(United Kingdom) and giving this error.

How to check if using Google Chrome:
Navigate to settings, Advanced, Languages, Language and set to United States.

Hopefully this helps!